# Manually call connectSlotsByName()

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-designer

I am experimenting with designer based Qt user interfaces. One of the features of a designer UI is auto connection of widget slots if they follow a special name pattern ("on_...").

However the connections seem to be established as soon as the UI is setup. I don't want this to happen. I want to programmatically modify the UI after loading, without getting unnecessary slot calls.

So, is it possible to explicitly control when these connections are established, i.e. when connectSlotsByName() is called?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `QObject::blockSignals` to block unnecessary signals for some time,
like this:

```
widget->blockSignals(true);
//do work
widget->blockSignals(false);
```

also you can call `disconnect` and then `connect` for specific signals.

Comment: Those are good workarounds. Thanks. I decided to avoid the automatic feature completely. (in addition to the above problem self made connections allow compile time checks of the connections).

Comment: There is also extension of clang static anaylyzer that can check generated signal/slots connections at compile time http://reviews.llvm.org/D14592 and standalone tool https://github.com/etaoins/qconnectlint